# Greenpipes is eating CPU while i am not using it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using Masstransit version 7.3.1 and rabbitmq to create a messaging mechanism (I am sending a message with each request the API receives) and I installed the Greenpipes library to use it later but after some monitoring I found out that Greenpipes is using a lot of CPU (see the image).

Does Masstransit use Greenpipes? And why is Greenpipes' CPU usage so high even though I am not using it directly?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the image showing? The percentage of the CPU usage for the process? Or it’s using 38% of a core? Whole CPU? Because if it’s just part of the process’ CPU usage it isn’t necessarily much

Comment: of the total CPU usage

Comment: I'm guessing you are probably using the library incorrectly, like an infinite read loop or something, but without code cannot say.

Comment: nope, i would notice that in that case , i removed the greenpipes reference and no error appeared  , i added Greenpipes only to be able to use IRetryConfigurator in the MessageRetry policy but i am not using it yet .  i am wondering if Masstransit uses Greenpipes  ? in case if Masstransit detect the existance of Greenpipes so it uses it instead of something in  .NET

Comment: @Charlieface you can see that Greenpipes and Masstransit are using quite the same amount of CPU .

Comment: When I said "library" I was referring to MassTransit. Please show relevant code.

Comment: I am using a simple Request/response pattern with a simple consumer,  the consumer is reading data from the db and if it uses a lot of cpu that seems fine but I am asking about the relationship between masstransit and greenpipes and Chris answered me about that.  Thanks

Comment: I am using a simple Request/response pattern with a simple consumer,  the consumer is reading data from the db and if it uses a lot of cpu that seems fine but I am asking about the relationship between masstransit and greenpipes and Chris answered me about that.  Thanks

Comment: You say "simple Request/response pattern with a simple consumer" but that is not that simple to implement, and pretty easy to end up doing infinite loops. That's why I asked to see relevant code. A screenshot of an error is next to useless

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit uses GreenPipes as the underlying pipe/filter library. GreenPipes was merged into MassTransit v8, removing the external assembly and namespace challenges.

If you're seeing CPU usage, you're likely doing something (or possibly even something wrong) that uses the CPU.

Comment: is greenpipes needed when targeting Masstransit 7.3.1 not V8 ? , i have been using Masstransit (old  7.3.1 version seperate greenpipes reference)  without greenpipes but when i wanted to add MessageRetry policy i needed IRetryConfigurator so that is why i added Greenpipes  into my project  . why i see that masstrnasit and greenpipes are  using  the same amount of CPU while i am not even using greenpipes directly into my code (even i am not using MessageRetry during this monitoring)

Comment: You haven't been using it without GreenPipes, since it's required by MassTransit. You just didn't have a direct reference to it.